# How I can recover a previous version of a file?

Tags: files, data-recovery, versions

I modified a `.txt` file and saved it. When I opened it again, I saw that I deleted one thing from the last version I saved. So I would like to know if I can recover what I deleted?

This file is very important to me. You have to help me! My life is on this file.

I didn't delete anything, I only edited the file. When I tried to save I had get an error saying that it could not read some characters so I closed the editor and when I opened it again some lines just disappeared.

Answer (score 10):

If you used GEdit and you havent disabled the backup function, then there must be a hidden file with name similar to your file but with ~ appended to it. So if your file name is `somefile.txt` then look for `somefile.txt~` in the same directory. This is the backup file and will give you your files state before last save.

Comment: How i turn on hidden files? Because i can't see any ~somefile.txt

Comment: Control+H or `View → Show Hidden Files`.

Comment: Only ....htaccess ;)

Answer (score 8):

binW's solution is the only solution for a problem like this where you have no backup or other versioning software in place. It is a one-time rescue that may help you this one time. If you save again, that backup will be replaced and you lose anything from before that backup. I hope this works for you.

Generally speaking, if you need version control or backup, **use backup or version control software**. You say this is a critical file so you should treat it like one. Look at version-control tools like `git` or `bzr` and [RabitVCS](http://www.rabbitvcs.org/) to tie them into the normal user interface.

But that is not enough. If this file is as critical to your existence as you suggest, please do some backups once in a while. There's no excuse these days not to. They take (at most) an hour to set up and using tools like DropBox or Amazon S3, are extremely cheap to store quite a lot of data off-site. Take a look at [the available backup tools](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools).

Neither of these systems will provide you with complete peace of mind. You want both a VCS for short-term and long-term histories and an off-site backup for long term data integrity.

Comment: Yhea! I have dropbox and i know that backups is important. I was to make one copy for the coming month. From now i will use Google Docs because i have acess to previous file versions and is on the cloud, so i dont lose it.

Comment: Still... Don't rely on that as your only copy. Google had lost user data before.

Comment: I think would be a good idea to offuscate /etc text-plain files and be able to versioning it on local machine ...

Answer (score -1):

This saved my life, while I was using Google Drive (insync / non-free).

- Enter Google Drive in the web browser; right-click on the file;
- Click "Manage versions" (File lasts 30 days in google drive server or max. 100 versions);
- Download the version of interest

Comment: And if OP'sfile is on a local mounted partition ? How do you expect Google drive to help in that case ? Hint: it doesn't.

Comment: A local mounted partition can be synced to GD